# Fold with closure that returns a Result

Tags: rust, fold, rust-result

I'm using the regex crate to find some text with this regex:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref FIND_STEPS_RE: Regex =
        Regex::new(r"my regex").unwrap();
}
```

I want to find all possible captures and iterate over them:

```
FIND_STEPS_RE.captures_iter(script_slice)
```

Each captured element consists of 2 values: an operation and a number. For example, the output could be:

```
[("+", "10"), ("-", "20"), ("*", "2")]
```

I want to iterate over it, parse the numbers and apply the operation.

I tried:

```
let e = FIND_STEPS_RE.captures_iter(script_slice)
    .fold(0, |sum, value| apply_decoding_step)?;
```

where `apply_decoding_step` is:

```
fn apply_decoding_step(sum: i32, capture: regex::Captures<>) -> Result<i32> {
    let number = parse_number(&capture[2])?;

    match  &capture[1] {
        "+" => Ok(s + number),
        "-" => Ok(s - number),
        "*" => Ok(s * number),
        "/" => Ok(s / number),
        _ => bail!("Unknown step operator"),
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<fn(i32, regex::Captures<'_>) -> std::result::Result<i32, Error> {apply_decoding_step} as std::ops::FnOnce<(i32, regex::Captures<'_>)>>::Output == i32`
   --> src/main.rs:122:10
    |
122 |         .fold(seed, apply_decoding_step);
    |          ^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found i32
    |
    = note: expected type `std::result::Result<i32, Error>`
               found type `i32`
```

I assume this is because I'm trying to fold a `Result` into a `i32`, but since I need to parse the second capture value and also need that `otherwise` case in my `match`, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 15):

As [jupp0r states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317883/155423), the initial value of `Iterator::fold` must be of the same type as the return value of the closure.

## Rust 1.26

You can use [`Iterator::try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) instead. This will exit iteration on the first failure:

```
let result = x.iter().try_fold(0, |acc, &i| apply_decoding_step(acc, i));
```

Complete example:

```
fn main() {
    let x = [("+", "10"), ("-", "20"), ("*", "2")];

    let result = x.iter().try_fold(0, |acc, &i| apply_decoding_step(acc, i));

    println!("{:?}", result);
}

fn apply_decoding_step(sum: i32, capture: (&str, &str)) -> Result<i32, ()> {
    let number: i32 = capture.1.parse().expect("nope");

    match capture.0 {
        "+" => Ok(sum + number),
        "-" => Ok(sum - number),
        "*" => Ok(sum * number),
        "/" => Ok(sum / number),
        _ => Err(()),
    }
}
```

## Rust 1.0

I'd recommend using `Result::and_then` to skip nothing in the fold when an error has occurred:

```
let result = x.iter().fold(Ok(0), |acc, &i| {
    acc.and_then(|acc| apply_decoding_step(acc, i))
});
```

The problem here is that the `fold` body is executed for every element in the iterator, even once an error occurs.

Here's an enterprise-grade solution where the main benefit is that iteration will end as soon as the first `Err` is encountered, instead of spinning through the rest of the list. Secondary benefits include the ability to write very fine-grained tests for each piece (parsing from a string, arithmetic operations, accumulation, etc.):

```
fn main() {
    let x = [("+", "10"), ("-", "20"), ("*", "2")];

    let result: Result<Accumulator, ()> = x
        .iter()
        .map(|&(op, val)| {
            let op = op.parse::<Op>()?;
            let val = val.parse::<i32>().map_err(|_| ())?;
            Ok((op, val))
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}

use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
}

impl Op {
    fn apply(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        use Op::*;

        match *self {
            Add => a + b,
            Sub => a - b,
            Mul => a * b,
            Div => a / b,
        }
    }
}

impl FromStr for Op {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        use Op::*;

        match s {
            "+" => Ok(Add),
            "-" => Ok(Sub),
            "*" => Ok(Mul),
            "/" => Ok(Div),
            _ => Err(()),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Accumulator(i32);

impl<'a> FromIterator<(Op, i32)> for Accumulator {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = (Op, i32)>,
    {
        Accumulator(
            iter.into_iter()
                .fold(0, |acc, (op, val)| op.apply(acc, val)),
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a closer look at the type signature for `fold`:

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B
 where
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
{ ... }
```

`init` has to have the same type as the return value of `f`. This is also what the compiler tells you in the error message. You could do

```
fn apply_decoding_step(sum: Result<i32>, capture: regex::Captures<>) -> Result<i32> {
    match sum {
        Err(_) => sum,
        Ok(s) => {      
            let number = parse_number(&capture[2])?;
            match  &capture[1] {
                "+" => Ok(s + number),
                "-" => Ok(s - number),
                "*" => Ok(s * number),
                "/" => Ok(s / number),
                _ => bail!("Unknown step operator"),
           }
       }
    }
}
```

And then call it with an `Ok` seed:

```
.fold(Ok(seed), apply_decoding_step);
```

Now, if any failure occurs, your `fold` returns an `Err`.

Comment: Wouldn't `let sum = sum?;` be shorter?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `Iterator` by a custom `fold_result` function like this (using the full path to `Result` because it seems you're importing a `Result` type generated by `error_chain`):

```
trait IterExtFoldResult: Iterator + Sized {
    #[inline]
    fn fold_result<B, F, E>(self, mut init: B, mut f: F) -> ::std::result::Result<B, E>
    where
        F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> ::std::result::Result<B, E>,
    {
        for i in self {
            init = f(init, i)?;
        }
        Ok(init)
    }
}
impl<I: Iterator> IterExtFoldResult for I {}
```

and use it like `.fold_result(0, apply_decoding_step)`.

That way `fold` aborts when `f` returned an error; if you forward the error in `f` the compiler might or might not optimize to an early return.

[Full example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=58b5800d0a6fd0a35f7e08af8ce8e3a1&version=stable)